# Creating a 3 column HTML table with dynamic data in Django

Tags: python, html, django, xhtml

I am trying to create a dynamic HTML table with 3 columns and 3 rows. Each column will have 3 records from the database so there will be 9 total records displayed (if they have 9 friends. otherwise just however many they have). I am doing this to mainly display small user profile pictures with their friends' usernames on the users homepage. Its going to be a list of 9 of their friends. I am using Django and cannot seem to find a tutorial showing how to display only 3 records per row if I retrieve 9 total records. Any help would be appreciated whether it be a link to a tutorial or info on how to solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use the [**`forloop.counter`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) and do something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
{% for person in people %}
        <td>{{ person }}</td>
    {% if not forloop.last and forloop.counter == 3 or forloop.counter == 6 %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

or roll a custom template tag. One [**`here`**](http://herself.movielady.net/2008/07/16/split-list-to-columns-django-template-tag/) looks like its doing what you want.

looks like this SO question is related:

[Render one queryset into 2 div columns (django template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610178/render-one-queryset-into-2-div-columns-django-template)

[EDIT] : should be "counter" not "count"

Answer (score 1):

This snippet might also be useful in this context: [Group sequence into rows and columns for a TABLE](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2361/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `{% if friends|length == 9 %}` to check if you have 9 records.

Comment: I found the answer.. I did the following after tweaking what you said @amateur.

    {% for f in friends %}
  {% if forloop.counter == 0 or forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
   <tr>
  {% endif %}
   <td><a href="/{{ f.to_friend.username }}/"><img src="{{ f.to_friend.profile_pic }}" class="small-pic" /><br />{{ f.to_friend.username }}</a></td>
  {% if forloop.counter == 0 or forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
  </tr>
  {% endif %}{% endfor %}

Comment: @Corey if your going to post a comment with code in it at least use backtiks ie: ` to wrap that code in so its displayed correctly :-)